# JIT of R code using Ra

Tags: r, jit

I just discovered [Ra](http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/ra/) from Ubuntu repositories. Has anyone used it in actual projects? Have you encountered any problems and are there any trade offs with using Ra instead of R or JIT in general?

Comment: Oh, cool. On the other hand, it does encourage the use of non-vectorized programming, which sorta defeats the purpose of much of R's design!

Comment: It is not even a real JIT, rather a faster interpreter. IMO it is nicer to embed C code, then the results are much more predicable.

Comment: Its still slower than vectorized code so I don't think it encourages using loops. And in some problems you just need to use a loop.

Comment: Well it all depends. Look at the 'distribution of determinant' looping example, originally from 'S Programming', picked up by Ra and the running example in my 'Intro to HPC with R' slides.  Ra and jit give you a significant boost 'for free'.  This can be a real help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I like it. But then it is in Ubuntu ... because I created the Debian package in the first place.  And I feature Ra and jit in my 'Intro to High-Performance Computing with R' tutorials (next one on Tuesday at [*useR!* 2010](http://useR2010.org)).

But sadly, Steven never got the feedback he anticipated and has stopped updating Ra. The most recent version is R 2.9.*, i.e. from a year ago.  This would be worth keeping alive, but a few more people (with highly specialized knowledge) would need to appear on the scene to help...

Comment: Thanks for the packaging and for the answer. I had a look at your slides and it definitely seems interesting. Let's hope he'll find some help and keeps maintaining it.

Comment: Is Luke Tierney working on some improvements to the R interpreter that may pave the way for things like JIT in the main R distribution?

Comment: Yes he is. But the he has been for most of the last decade and you never know about ETAs. He has been in contact with Steve too though.  Anyway, Luke will talk at useR! next week and mention some of this.  But this is generally not 'hold your breath' material.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question was asked the {compiler} R package was introduced.  I wrote a post describing what I have found this far regarding the use of JIT and R:

http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/04/speed-up-your-r-code-using-a-just-in-time-jit-compiler/

The post describes some advances since what Dirk wrote in his reply (several of the links in the post are actually to Dirk's newer articles regarding this topic)

I hope this help future R people searching on this topic.